# Как создаётся дизайн приложения на android

Tags: android, дизайн

Написал приложение, используя стандартные(топорные) виджеты. Как делается красивый дизайн приложения? Используя XML или просто вставка картинок вместо кнопок? Подскажите как это лучше сделать? Какие статьи почитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Подобное называется гайдлайном](https://material.google.com/#), и здесь можете ознакомиться со всеми принципами.

Для того, чтобы использовать это в своем приложении, вам нужно будет обратиться к библиотеке поддержки `AppCompat` - когда я только столкнулся с андроидом, долго не мог понять, откуда берутся табы, FAB, анимации от `Coordinator Layout` и тд.

Надеюсь, дал исчерпывающий ответ. Если будут какие-то вопросы, допишите в комментарий, обновлю.

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` один из компонентов библиотеки поддержки AppCompat, а не название библиотеки.

Comment: @pavlofff точно, бес попутал, сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю кнопки через ImageView, потом цепляю на них OnClickListener. Но в любом случае вся разметка делается через xml. 
Теоретически можно через LayoutParams верстать, но это плохая практика

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще посмотреть тут [Material Design: на Луну и обратно](https://habrahabr.ru/company/redmadrobot/blog/252773/)